# Symfony 3 Inject service into entity repository

Tags: php, symfony

I tried inject memcached service into entity repository, but my variant not work.

```
services:
  work.repository.company:
    class: WorkBundle\Repository\CompanyRepository
    factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', getRepository]
    arguments:
        - 'WorkBundle:Company'
    calls:
        - [setCacheService, ['@memcache.default']]
```

CompanyRepository have setter setCacheService, but it's not called.

```
class CompanyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getCompaniesCount', array($this, 'getCompaniesCount'))
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCompaniesCount()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('WorkBundle:Company')->getActiveCompaniesCount();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'work_company_extension';
    }
}
```

Why this code not works?

Comment: Bad practise! Do like shown here: [Manually caching resources with memcached in symfony - version 1](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/gbmc/manually-caching-resources-with-memcached-in-symfony-version-1) or [Manually caching resources with memcached in symfony - version 2](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/9pst/manually-caching-resources-with-memcached-in-symfony-version-2)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Have you registered `repositoryClass` in your `WorkBundle:Company` entity? Your entity should contain something like: `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Work\Company")` or yaml equivalent.</s>

You should let Symfony create the repository by injecting `work.repository.company` into your Twig extension.

Comment: Using get from inside of a twig extension will not end well.  Perhaps you meant to suggest injecting the repository instead of injecting the entity manager?